# Is it possible to play audio files through the onboard system speaker?

Tags: command-line, server, sound, 22.04

Please don't start throwing "stones" at me, I'm just curious. Is it possible to play an audio file, such as `.wav`, `.mp3`, or `.ogg`, through the **onboard system speaker** of a machine equipped with **[this](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41M-Combo-rev-20#ov)** motherboard and running **Ubuntu Server**? If so, how can I do that? Which program should I use? Are there any examples or resources you could provide?

---

**EDIT:** And when I say **onboard system speaker**, I mean this:
[image]

Comment: I know for a fact that this is possible. I remember an old DOS game that could play samples and music through the onboard PC speaker (and yes, it sounded really bad!).  However, if there's any current software that can do this is another topic entirely.

Comment: It's possible using current Ubuntu systems as well, as I perform QA (*mostly using Desktop systems however*) and often have audio play out through the internal machine speakers because I don't have speakers connected (*and most QA I perform is on desktops, but it also works on laptops*). I don't know if it'd work on Server hardware intended for rack-mount, as those systems are usually outside of audible range & alerts are usually via LED/lights flashing

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'm sure it won't sound very good, but I just want to play some "voice messages" like "Ubuntu server is ready for use," etc. I'm not trying to play any songs or anything like that. :)

Comment: @guiverc in my case, it's an old home PC that I've turned into a file server.

Comment: More info here (the Arch Wiki is always a good source of technical info): https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PC_speaker

Comment: Here's a thread on how someone got it working using espeak on Slackware, https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-do-you-use-snd-pcsp-in-slackware-14-1-a-4175534306/. There's a lot at the start on turning on the speaker, skip to the end.

Comment: You answered "*I just want to play some "voice messages"*" which reminded me of Knoppix, which says "*Initiating Startup Sequence*" when it boots, grabbed a thumb-drive of whatever version of Knoppix was on it, and grabbed the top laptop in a pile.. Inserted & booted & sure enough I hear "*Initiating Startup Sequence*" from the laptop.  I'm betting it's just a `paplay` used for that audio, as it's the same low-quality audio I hear from Ubuntu when testing `vlc`, or playing `mp3` files. Nothing is required as stated before as Ubuntu Desktop systems do it on hardware with no config/change

Comment: My prior comment is specific to desktops, as I test Ubuntu Desktop & *flavors*, and thus have less actual experience with servers (*besides I only have laptop/desktop systems where I am, accessing my servers remotely so I'd not even hear any audio they played even if they had decent audio on max volume*). Not all servers have speakers, but I'd expect just ensuring *pulse audio* was installed (which will include the `paplay` I mentioned prior comment) would have a high chance of working, if not contrast the *manifest* of a desktop & server system for other differences, assuming hardware good

Comment: @guiverc so, if I understand correctly, can I play an audio file through the system speaker using PulseAudio?

Comment: @pbhj I can’t understand what he is doing… I don’t know where to start from…

Comment: Given the laptop & desktop systems I use in QA, and used with Knoppix have nothing but whatever internal speaker they came with, that's what I was talking about. The sound is *tinny* and sounds *remote*, in fact often during QA, especially where I didn't expect it, I'm assuming I'm hearing a different PC try and give an alert & often *mute* the current device out of habit, and only then realize that stopped the sound; ie. it was the local device. I don't use Ubuntu Server installs though, only Desktop installs (especially *flavors*, especially the *flavor* team I'm most heavily involved with)

Comment: For those who have already commented, please recheck my question. It has been updated.

Comment: That is exactly what I was referring to; I don't see any change though except a diagram specific to a brand/model of motherboard of which we have no details (*except for part of a picture from manual/documentation*)

Comment: @guiverc This is the motherboard I'm referring to: [ https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41M-Combo-rev-20#ov ]. I just wanted to clarify that I'm specifically talking about that motherboard's speaker, to avoid any misunderstanding. That's where I want to send the audio and I don't know how.

Comment: I grabbed a nearby laptop which has a recent QA-tested install (*mantic* given that's about to release if a few hours as 23.10), and only had to `sudo apt install pulseaudio-utils ubuntu-sounds` then a `cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` to jump to where the installed sounds are, and a simple `paplay desktop-login.ogg` has it play the installed sound file thru the laptops internal speakers (*this device comes with a speaker attached to the motherboard on purchase*). As stated I'd expect that to be pretty much all that is required for a server install but I don't have server install to test

Comment: the first package I installed (`pulseuadio-utils`) I only used to install `paplay` so I had a CLI tool available so I could play a mp3 file... The second (`ubuntu-sounds`) was to give me a mp3 file to play (*this box didn't have any that I could see, but I didn't look far as its a new install*).. turns out I noted only OGG files, so used that instead in the *pulse audio play* (`paplay`) command.. and as no plugged in speakers I get it thru the very *tinny* (or *crappy*) box speaker(s)... though I needed to do it in a quiet room to hear it (it's rather quiet)

Comment: @guiverc I've already tried all of these steps and I've also adjusted the settings in `alsamixer`. Despite this, I only get sound when I connect external speakers! Unless the audio files are play so low from the onboard speaker that I can't hear them.

Comment: I don't have a *fresh* Server install I can test with (*or for my own servers they're not local so I'd not hear anything anyway*); I'm using new QA installs (*thus currently they're all mantic; once its released they'll be 22.04.4 next*) but server vs desktop can differ thus why I mentioned [*manifest comparison*](https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest). Yes some hardware can require more than the default (most will just work though). I'd not have touched ALSA using only PA (*pulse audio*) myself (ALSA can change defaults away from default).